# Feature with List and registration form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, feature

I am new to SharePoint and want to discuss an issue
I want to create a feature that will create custom application page (registration form) and a custom list to store registration form's data. I can create list but i have no idea about how to create registration form ? Should i create .ascx Control for registration form and then add that Control to feature ? Is it correct idea ?
Secondly, How i create custom application page in SharePoint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's faily easy to create a custom application page. You can add a application page in existing solution or new solution. Example below is with Empty SharePoint Project template:

[image]

[image]

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CustomApplicationPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="CustomApplicationPage.Layouts.CustomApplicationPage.CustomApplicationPage" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" %>
<asp:Content ID="PageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="PageTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">My Custom Application Page
  <asp:Label runat="server" Text="My Custom Page"></asp:Label>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="PageTitleInTitleArea" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" >
My Application Page
</asp:Content>
```

You can also add User Control (ascx) to custom application page as well.

Comment: Ok! But i want to create application page within feature ?How feature will create application page under featureActivated method??

Comment: You can use module element to provision application page. Add Module name as "Pages" and url as "_Layouts"